# Should I restrict my api with CORS?

Tags: api, web-api

Should I restrict my backend API (`api.cool-domain.com`) to be only accessible by my frontend (`cool-domain.com`)? Seems like it will provide *some* amount of additional security, I am just asking is it worth the hassle, because we all know about hundreds of public apis without such CORS restrictions.

Comment: 1) Why do you name it "hassle"? It is trivial, you just add a header to the response. 2) Only you can decide what security measures make sense in your case. Analyze what are your threats, what are the risks, what will be the costs if the risk occurs, what will it cost to implement CORS protection. Then you will see if it makes sense in your particular case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CORS is **not** a security feature. Only code running in browsers will care for CORS because browsers will use CORS.

Any regular application is free to call your API ignoring CORS.

Please repeat: CORS is not a security feature.

That said: why not. If you want it only called from your frontend, just do it. It won't keep others from calling you anyway though. it's a nice guideline, that nobody has to adhere to.